# How to add the READONLY style to a wxTextCtrl text box in C++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

was wondering how to add the REARONLY style to a TextCtrl in C++ for the wxWidgets framework. Im a complete noob to C++ and wxWidgets and couldn't find an comprehensible answer online. All I want to do is have a basic on screen text box holding a label text for an input text box below it. So, if im just ignorant to a better method, please let me know.

`m_txt_box = new wxTextCtrl (this, wxID_ANY, "Test", wxPoint(100, 500), wxSize(30, 30));`

Comment: Did you check the documentation for [wxTextCtrl](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_text_ctrl.html)?

Comment: Yeah, I just seemed to have misplaced a comma. My fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m_txt_box = new wxTextCtrl (this, wxID_ANY, "Test", wxPoint(100, 500), wxSize(30, 30), 
    wxTE_READONLY);
```

`long style = 0` is `wxTextCtrl` constructor parameter after `wxSize size`. Required style is `wxTE_READONLY`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `wxStaticText`.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, previous fixed my issue but this is a better fit. Much appreciated.